# nodejs http2 request - where can I find the clients ip address

Tags: node.js, http2

I am building a complex SPA using Polymer to replicate an Access Application.  I want to use http2 to avoid the maintenance nightmare of merging source files to get appropriate performance.

I have built myself the start of the application, log in via a sql server database. and am now starting to debug things.

I am trying to retrieve the clientip address using answers I have found on here

```
var ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] ||
   req.connection.remoteAddress ||
   req.socket.remoteAddress ||
   req.connection.socket.remoteAddress;
```

but unfortunately at this point the server crashes.  Digging around with the debugger (given req is the request object) there is no 'x-forwarded-for'header, no connection object (except inside socket) and this is what kills this statement as can't access remoteAddress of undefined.  But I cannot find a remoteaddress field in any object derived from req.

I am using https://github.com/molnarg/node-http2 which appears to be the only implementation around.  There is some mention of endpoint.js library in the documentation but the links are broken, so I have no idea how to access an endpoint object.

In order to get the correct certificates, I am using the ones from pastrial.hartley-consultants.com and changed my in house dns server to give me my development machine as its ip address.  I am accessing it via a browser on the same machine. So client and server machines should both have 192.168.0.xx IP addresses which just happen to be the same.

So question is - where is the IP address of the client exposed to the server (or indeed is it in http2)

Comment: am not sure , but have you tried checking for req.headers['x-real-ip'] ?

Comment: the only header elements are accept, accept-encoding, accept-language, cookie, host, upgrade-insecure-requests and user-agent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is it is in `req.remoteAddress`

Comment: Sometimes. But sometimes it's null.